# Cannot make a simple redim using VbScript in ASP

Tags: vbscript

I've the following code in ASP:

```
<%@ Language= "VBScript" %> 
[...]
dim myarray(4)
redim myarray(5)
```

And when I try to execute the code I get the error An error occurred on the server when processing the URL, shown in the browser.

I thougth that maybe myarray needed to be declared like dim myarray() AS Integer to be declared as a dynamic array, but just declaring it causes the same error.

Maybe ASP doesn't support array resizing with VbScript, though I would find that fact extremely strange.

Is there something I'm missing that would allow the array to be properly resized?

Answer (score 1):

You can't ReDim a fixed (= dimmed to a specific number) array. See docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx).

Demo:

```
>> Dim a
>> ReDim a(0)
>> a(0) = 0
>> ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
>> a(1) = 1
>> WScript.Echo Join(a)
>>
0 1
>>
```